# can't get only the date from datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm really mad how is possible c# not to have a simple date format without the annoying hour after that

here is my problem:

I've got a class

```
public class Dates
   {
       // private int excursionID;
        private int excursion_date_ID;
        private DateTime  startdates;
        private double prices;

       /* public  int ExcursionID
        {
            get { return excursionID; }
            set { excursionID = value; }

        }*/
        public int Excursion_date_ID
        {
            get { return excursion_date_ID; }
            set { excursion_date_ID = value; }
        }
        public DateTime StartDates
        {
            get { return startdates.Date; }
            set { startdates = value.Date; }
        }

        public  double Prices
        {
            get { return prices; }
            set { prices = value; }
        }

        public Dates() { }
       }
   }
```

Then On PageLoad I get from  the database some data

```
public List<Dates> GetDates()
        {
            List<Dates> datesList = new List<Dates>();

            string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=excursion;Trusted_Connection=true";
            string excursionnID = Request.QueryString["ExcursionID"];
            string query =
        "SELECT Excursion_date_ID, Start_date, Price FROM EXCURSION_DATES WHERE EXCURSION_ID='" + excursionnID + "'";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                int s=0;
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Dates dates = new Dates();

                    // dates.ExcursionID = Convert.ToInt32(rd["Excursion_ID"]);
                    dates.Excursion_date_ID=Convert.ToInt32(rd["Excursion_date_ID"]);
                    DateTime excursiondatetime = (DateTime)rd["Start_date"];
                    dates.StartDates = excursiondatetime.Date;
                    dates.Prices = Convert.ToDouble(rd["Price"]);
                    datesList.Add(dates);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {

            }
            return datesList;
        }
```

Then I only return fill one GridView with the returnes list 
here is my Page_Load

```
 Dates date = new Dates();
            List<Dates> listDate = new List<Dates>();
            listDate = GetDates();
            gvDates.DataSource = listDate;
            gvDates.DataBind
```

Now can someone explain why I keep getting the hour part when you see that I only get the date part

Comment: `Date` still returns a `DateTime`, which includes well, date and time. If you only want to display the date you need a string format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Is it showing date and time of 00:00:00? If so, you might want to change the dusplay format to date only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need too format your date like

```
somedate.ToString("d")
```

There are also some other dateformats available

Comment: if you do that in a gridview, sorting the column will sort in alphabetical order rather than by the value of the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bound field, you need to do this:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

You can [change the date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) however you like